# How to add custom rules in sonarqube 5.1+

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have a requirement to add few more rules to the existing rules. But I am unable to find any way for the latest version of sonarqube i.e 5.1+
Can someone tell me how to do that?

As we know in the latest version, we already have sonarway of rules, which get caught as issues when we run sonar runner for any language specific plugin. I want to add few more rules to the existing rules, which would be caught while running sonar runner.

`Manual rules are like we need to do it manually.`

I Have done a lot of research before posting the question.

Comment: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules might be a good starting point.

Comment: @benzonico
so we need to code it. I thought, it was just a matter of uploading some xml file. I am not sure ? I new to sonarqube

Comment: Can you precise in your question what you are trying to achieve ? on which language do you want to add rule ? for which rule engine  ? or do you want to tune the quality profile ? It is very hard to help you with so sparse information.

Comment: @benzonico 
As we know in the latest version, we already have sonarway of rules, which identifies when we run sonar runner for any language specific plugin. I want to add few more rules to the existing rules, which would be caught while running sonar runner.

Comment: @benzonico
actually php rules which are already present are not enough for drupal standards. We need to add more to it. Before we some option like import an XML which did the job.

Answer (score 0):

First, the set of available rules is defined by the installed plugins, it does not depend on the version of SonarQube.

Some language plugins support custom rules. As mentioned by benzonico, a [documentation on writing custom rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules) is available. Custom rules can be written in Java or XPath depending on the language plugin.

If you don't want to write custom rules, you have to find a plugin which implements the rule you need. The PHP plugin used to provide some integration with external tools like PHPCodeSniffer and supported the import of a quality profile through XML. However, as mentioned in the [documentation of this plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPHP), that feature was removed in version 2.0.

Comment: Yeah that's what the feature is removed, before it was possible through some XML. Actually I need perfect rules for drupal standards. Writing custom rules is like programming a plugin. Is there a way to edit the existing plugin and add new rules some how ?